# Always run a program as root without typing sudo on RHLE?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo

I have a program called 'myprogram'. I want to be able to type, from the cmd line:

```
>$ myprogram
```

and have it automatically run as root. As in I want the above command to be translated to,

```
>$ sudo myprogram
```

I plan to edit the sudoers file so that when invoked, this specific program doesn't need a password to be entered.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Safest way is to define an alias or function in your .bashrc (assuming your shell is bash):

```
alias myprogram='sudo myprogram'
myprogram() { sudo /path/to/myprogram "$@"; }
```